# SilverStripe SMTP authentication instead of PHP mail() function

Tags: php, silverstripe

My hosting provider (webhosting.uk.com) for security reason has disabled the PHP mail() function requiring to update our code using a SMTP authentication. I have no idea how to change the code, I suppose it's in the sapphire folder? At the moment the contact form on my website doesn't send the email to the recipient and the newsletter module fails to send... Can anyone help me in this, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there should be a rule ordering to add these odd application names to the question title. it's not PHP, its some silverstrippe whatever it is

Comment: added SilverStripe to the title, happy now? Relax dude

Comment: thanks. there are hundreds of odd applications and you all questioners sure that everyone knows them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found the solution: http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/7991

Comment: Don't mess around with core - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Don't change the code in core - it will make updates complicated and isn't necessary.

There's a dedicated module for this problem: https://github.com/xeraa/silverstripe-smtp
Disclaimer: I'm the author, but it's free + BSD licensed so there's no reason for not using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a site I maintain at webhosting. I've not yet resolved the issue (lack of time), but webhosting did provide an example way to use SMTP authentication for email sending.

This is the link the mail I got from webhosting: http://taverham.webhosting.uk.com/auth.txt.  That asks you do download a zip file from [here](http://taverham.webhosting.uk.com/contact.zip), which contains php script code that will allow you to use SMTP authentication.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Nick, the problem is not changing the mail function to the SMTP, the problem is how to change it in the SilverStripe source code, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that silverstripe was involved, sorry! :)